# php---a line in the if loop

Tags: php, oop

```
   if(!$id){
if($page){ // load by name
$r=Page::getInstanceByName($page);
  if($r && isset($r->id))$id=$r->id;
    unset($r);
 }
```

i am a newbie of oop, so i can't understand this line well,($r=Page::getInstanceByName($page);) anyone can explain it for me. thank you,

Comment: Page::getInstanceByName($page) you call the `static` method: `getInstanceByName` of class `Page` with an argument called `$page`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class "page" has a function getInstanceByName that you're calling.

The function is static, wich means you can call it without actually making an object. It does not need anything from the Page class.

as opposed to:

```
$myPage = new Page();
$myPage->getInstanceByName($page);
```

the function might look like this;

```
public static function getInstanceByName($page){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) design to return object from given page specification (most likely a page name).

Answer (score 0):

```
$r = Page::getInstanceByName($page);
```

- calling a static method `getInstanceByName` on class `Page` (this should be public static method)
- `$page` is the argument pass into the static method
- result return by the above static method will set into variable `$r`

Comment: class page, not object page. An object is an instance of an class.